# Twitter hashtag css3 coin animation

Tags: css, animation, twitter, hashtag

First I would like to apologise for the vagueness of my question and also if it has already been answered.

I was tasked to come up with a facebook app concept that is driven with tweeter `hashtags`.
I will have a coin spinning animation ( done in css or flash ) and when a user tweets using the supplied hashtags, his coin keeps spinning unless he does not tweet in like a two hour interval.

What would be best way to tackle this?
I have been trying to find some kind of information on how to do this, but all my searches have been futile so far and only leading to visualizing tweets (which I do not require).

If someone can come up with some light on the matter it would be much appreciated.